# How to generate a string out of an (error)object without actual printing?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I want to retrieve the string, generated by `write` for further processing without doing any actual output, but `write` seems always to also output into the REPL

```
CL-USER>(let ((err-string (write (make-instance 'error) :stream nil)))
          (do-awesome-stuff-with-string err-string))
<ERROR> ;;this is the printing I want to get rid of
"awesome-result"
```

**Why does `write` still outputs into the REPL, and how do I get rid of that?**

Comment: Some answers have addressed how you might get _a_ string representation of the error object along the lines of `#<error ...>`, like you'd see if you simply print it, you might also be interested in the functions [simple-condition-format-control and simple-condition-format-arguments](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_smp_cn.htm)), which you could use to reconstruct the message that you'd typically see if the error was signaled.  This only works for subclasses of `simple-condition` though, so it's a not quite as widely applicable.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I was looking for a general approach

Comment: and that's why I didn't post it as an answer.  I still expect that someone else who finds this question might find that information useful, depending on what they're trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `with-output-to-string` for this. Here's an example:

```
(flet ((do-awesome-stuff-with-string (string)
         (concatenate 'string string " is awesome!")))
  (let ((err-string (with-output-to-string (s)
                      (write (make-instance 'error) :stream s))))
    (do-awesome-stuff-with-string err-string)))
;; => "#<ERROR {25813951}> is awesome!"
```

Here's [here's](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_out_.htm) the HyperSpec entry on `with-output-to-string`.

The reason `(write (make-instance 'error) :stream nil)` doesn't work is that the `:stream` argument to `write` is a [stream designator](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#stream_designator) and in that context `nil` is shorthand for `*standard-output*`. (The fact that `format` instead takes `nil` to mean that it should return a string is a common point of confusion).

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that portably errors are made with `MAKE-CONDITION`. The standard does not say that errors are CLOS classes, so `MAKE-INSTANCE` might not work in some implementations.

There are two simple ways to get a string:

a) a textual description:

```
CL-USER 15 > (princ-to-string (make-condition 'error))
"The condition #<ERROR 4020311270> occurred"
```

b) the error object printed:

```
CL-USER 16 > (prin1-to-string (make-condition 'error))
"#<ERROR 402031158B>"
```